# How do I create a single measure, that slices the same data 3 different ways and unions it?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I've been trying for a day and a half now to figure out how to combine the same measure, in two different ways, in the same measure.  It's been broken into parts, I've tried to UNION them, calculate with IF statements, I even thought I could UNION 3 summary tables to get the right output.  I'm stuck using Excel 365 ProPlus (which I believe to be 2016 since Get and Transform and PowerPivot are built in).

The goal: I need to do this so that I can trick a PowerPivot table connected to the data model into displaying a) running total with b) a total line with c) a flat, non-running total Goal/Target line in the same measure.  I've been able to do a & b, however c is elusive.

[image]

I tried to calculate the data in stages, with the first two steps here being that no matter what I try I can't seem to get two filters to work at the same time:

```
Occbase:=CALCULATE([Occurrences],
FILTER('Final Dataset',
    'Final Dataset'[MainFilter] = ""))

CumOcc:=CALCULATE([Occbase],
FILTER(ALL(DimDate[DateValue]),
    DimDate[DateValue] <= MAX(DimDate[DateValue])))
```

These two measures will do part 1, filter the dataset, and then calculate from that filter a simple running total.  I've tried to do it in a single step but if the filter is working, then the running total won't work:

```
CombinedMakesRunningTotolStopWorking:=CALCULATE(SUM('Final Dataset'[xOccurrences]), FILTER(
        ALL(Dimdate[DateValue]),
        DimDate[DateValue] <= MAX(DimDate[DateValue]))
    ,FILTER(
        'Final Dataset',
        'Final Dataset'[MainFilter] = ""
        || 'Final Dataset'[Region] = "Ttl Occ MPR"  //I couldn't figure out how to calculate on the fly
        )                           //so I generated this total in PowerQuery
    )
```

The SQL dev in me decided to try to pull all three above separately and then use UNION and SUMMARIZE by the date value and the region value but received an even worse result...

```
TryHarder:=SUMX(UNION(
    SUMMARIZE(FILTER('Final Dataset',
            'Final Dataset'[Region] = "Ttl Occ MPR"),
        [Region],
        [DateValue],
        "OccurrencesXXX", CALCULATE([Occbase],
                            FILTER(ALL(DimDate[DateValue]),
                                DimDate[DateValue] <= MAX(DimDate[DateValue]))))
    ,
    SUMMARIZE(FILTER(ALL('Final Dataset'),
        'Final Dataset'[Region] = "PR Occ Goal"),
        [Region],
        [DateValue],
        "OccurrencesXXX", [Occurrences])
    ,
    SUMMARIZE(FILTER('Final Dataset',
        'Final Dataset'[MainFilter] = ""),
        [Region],
        [DateValue],
        "OccurrencesXXX", CALCULATE([Occbase],
                            FILTER(ALL(DimDate[DateValue]),
                                DimDate[DateValue] <= MAX(DimDate[DateValue]))))
    ), [OccurrencesXXX])
```

With the comically defeating result of:

[image]

I could give up and just generate a table for each chart in PowerQuery... but would have to generate a ton of tables.  I have to assume I'm doing something wrong with scope/context and I have a feeling my C#/SQL mindset is putting me at a huge disadvantage in learning DAX.  I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong and learn the DAX pattern and terminology to fix it.

Comment: Could you please explain your goal in more detail? I am trying to understand what "trick a PowerPivot table connected to the data model into displaying..." means.

Comment: Hi @RADO, The first picture shows what I am trying to achieve in a single DAX measure.  The stacked bars represent the cumulative/running total half of the measure.  The red line has been drawn onto the chart because it needs to be calculated differently in the same measure.  Think of it in terms of SingleMeasure:= IF [Region] = "Goal" then SUM('Table'[Value]) else cumulative sum 'Table'[Value].

Comment: What I don't understand is why it has to be a single measure. What's wrong with 3 separate measures?

Comment: The data is sliced by region in the pivot chart.  This causes the legend and it's attached data table to be overfilled with duplicate region values since a pivot chart is significantly less capable than say, a Power BI chart.  The Power BI chart knows to combine legend entries vs duplicating them.  I'll be doing this in Power Query since I don't think DAX is designed to handle this type of thing. I'll post an answer with what I did in the queries to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to setup a table that is not connected to the model, and then use that to determine what value you return.  Example below being for a unit of measure (UOM).   The idea being that the measure returned is dependent on the Unit of measure field, so adding it to the legend part of the pivot chart would return unit, case and ESU volume.  It also means you could use a slicer to toggle which fields are returned in the chart.

```
Volume:=IF( HASONEVALUE( 'Unit of Measure'[UOM] ),
    SWITCH(TRUE(),
        VALUES('Unit of Measure'[Order]) = 1, [Unit Volume],
        VALUES('Unit of Measure'[Order]) = 2, [Case Volume],
        VALUES('Unit of Measure'[Order]) = 3, [ESU Volume]
    ),
        [ESU Volume]
    )
```